# C#: Change Object from MainWindow in an Dialog using Gtk

Tags: c#, object, modal-dialog, gtk#

I think this is just a small problem, but I do not get solved.

I have a programm with a Gtk.Window and a Gtk.Dialog. In Window I use a self coded object. The Dialog needs to know the object in order to change it. When you click on the OK-Button, the changes must be known to the Window's object.

Can anyone give me an example of this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog has a Response event that you can hook and in the arguments passed to the handler is the dialog response button that was pressed.

```
var md = new MessageDialog (
            null,
            DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent,
            MessageType.Info,
            ButtonsType.OkCancel,
            "Your message");

md.Response += (o, args) => {
    if (args.ResponseId == ResponseType.Ok) {
        // do your stuff with the object
    }
};

md.Run ();
md.Destroy ();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but how can I access the input fields of the dialog there.

Comment: Are you still having trouble accessing input fields or did Kristof answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have created a dialogbox by extending the Gtk.DialogBox class:

```
public MyDialog : Gtk.DialogBox
{
    ...
}
```

Insite this class add Properties to get the values :

```
// The entry containing the customer name
private Entry _customerName;

// Gets or sets the customer name
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this._customerName.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        this._customerName.Text = value;
    }
}
```

So from you main window, you can get and set the content, as Skyler mentionned earlier.